# Cannot convert value of type Class.user to expected argument of type string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following error:

[image]

As you see in the image, and the interested part of code is this

```
class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var coordinate: (Double, Double)
        var type: String
    }

    /* var place = ["Caffè Spagar", "Duks", "Posta station", "Barnum", "Elephant Club", "Cinema", "Space", "Andromeda", "Rodolf", "Devil Chair"] */

    var rows = 0

   var users = [User]()

    let CS = User(name: "Caffè Spagar", images: UIImage(named: "Caffè Spagar.png")! , coordinate:(12345,54678), type: "Pub")
    let D = User(name: "Duks", images: UIImage(named: "Duks.png")! , coordinate:(13345,54128), type: "Shopping")
    let PS = User(name: "Posta station", images: UIImage(named: "Posta station.png")! , coordinate:(18795,34556), type: "Resturant")
    let B = User(name: "Barnum", images: UIImage(named: "Barnum.png")! , coordinate:(46655,43554), type: "Pub")
    let EC = User(name: "Elephant Club", images: UIImage(named: "Elephant Club.png")! , coordinate:(12325,21435), type: "Disco")
    let C = User(name: "Cinema", images: UIImage(named: "Cinema.png")! , coordinate:(11235,12343), type: "Cinema")
    let S = User(name: "Space", images: UIImage(named: "Space.png")! , coordinate:(12345,66432), type: "Cinema")
    let A = User(name: "Andromeda", images: UIImage(named: "Andromeda.png")! , coordinate:(64545,23443), type: "Sport")
    let R = User(name: "Rodolf", images: UIImage(named: "Rodolf.png")! , coordinate:(64545,34358), type: "Shopping")
    let DC = User(name: "Devil Chair", images: UIImage(named: "Devil Chair.png")! , coordinate:(56656,54678), type: "Shopping")





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      map.showsUserLocation = true
      map.delegate = self
      users.append(CS)
      users.append(D)
      users.append(PS)
      users.append(B)
      users.append(EC)
      users.append(C)
      users.append(S)
      users.append(A)
      users.append(R)
      users.append(DC)



    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        insertRowsMode3()
    }


    func insertRowsMode2() {

        for i in 0..<users.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, str: users[i])
        }

    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,str:String) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }
```

how can I modify to make it work? and I would like to know if this is the correct way to implement the coordinate in the code too.

Comment: you need to add use it like `users[i].name`. `users[i]` gives you user object not string object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `insertRowMode2` function like this,

```
func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:User) 
{
    let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
    rows = ind + 1
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
}
```

Comment: Welcome bero :)

Answer (score 0):

see your function! you declare it like `func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,str:String)` that means your function accepts `String` as second parameter and when you calling this function you are not paasing `String` because `users[i]` will not return string value as `User` is your Structure! you have to pass `String` to that function or change that function's parameter to `Any` so it can accepts any object!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Here you need to pass string instead of Uses class's object.

```
 func insertRowsMode2() {
         for (index, element) in users.enumerated() {
             let user =  element as! User 
              // do additional your work here 
            insertRowMode2(ind: index, user: user)

       }
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,user: User) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }
```

**OR change function**

```
  func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,user:User)
```

Comment: you need to replace your this func     func insertRowsMode2() {